# Sencha-touch list does not show data

Tags: list, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm quite new to Sencha-touch and I'm following the getting started video on the documentation website.

There is a part where the app shows blogposts in a list, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I have the same code in the video but it doesn't work.

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Blog', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype: 'blog',

config: {
    title: 'Blog',
    iconCls: 'star',

    items: {
        xtype: 'list',
        itemTpl: '{title}',

        store: {
                    autoload: true,
                    fields: ['title', 'link', 'author'],

                    proxy: {
                        type: 'jsonp',
                        url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
}
});
```

Has the code/library from sencha touch changed since the video or am I doing something wrong (and what)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a little while to figure out, but it is because the store is not loading. You may ask why, as you have specified `autoload` to be true? The reason is because it is `autoLoad` (notice the capital **L**).

:)

Comment: my god..
Thx! That's one mistake I won't make again!

Answer (score 0):

please download latest sencha 2.0 framework sdk ,I also faced same issue but after downloading and using sencha-touch-all. js ,everything works fine .Probs they have updated the 2.0 with added new js files like navigation view .Open your existing sdk and check in document whether you can find Ext.View.navigation exist or not.

Comment: I have the latest version. I checked in the sdk folder of my project just to be sure and I did find the View.js file in the navigation folder.